# Passing extra parameters to my data_autocomplete_source

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following requirement:-

1.A text box that have a data_autocomplete_source, as follow:-

> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Technology.Search, new {
>   data_autocomplete_source = Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Switch") })

2.Two radio buttons to select what is the keyword for doing the autocomplete search, either by name or number as follow:-

```
<input type="radio" name="searchType" value="number" /> number
<input type="radio" name="searchType" value="name"/>name
```

So my question if how I can pass the radio button selection , along with the autocomplete search term ?

My auto complete script looks as follow:-

```
$("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
        var target = $(this);
        target.autocomplete({ source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source"), minLength: 2, delay: 2000 });

    });
```

**EDIT**
i tried the following :-

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Technology.Search, new { data_autocomplete_source = Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Switch", new { SearchBy = Model.SearchBy}) })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(a=>a.SearchBy, "number", new { id = "number" })number
@Html.RadioButtonFor(a=>a.SearchBy, "Name", new { id = "name" })Name
```

But the SearchBy value will always be null ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a value not coming from the model that is why it's `null`. What I can suggest you is to pass the parameter in your JQuery function.
Then it can call your Action with the parameter from the client side.

```
 $("#myTextBoxSearch").each(function () {
    var searchByVal = $('input[name=SearchBy]:checked').val();  
    var target = $(this);
    target.autocomplete({ source:@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Switch", new { SearchBy = searchByVal}) , minLength: 2, delay: 2000 });

 });
```

If you have in your view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Technology.Search, new { id="myTextBoxSearch" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(a=>a.SearchBy, "number", new { id = "number" })number
@Html.RadioButtonFor(a=>a.SearchBy, "Name", new { id = "name" })Name
```

Note that you can use the name of the variable you want. I just show you a way.
I hope it will help you.